# Named pipe buffer wcscmp comparison

Tags: c++, powershell, pipe

Currently I'm having an issue when attempting to perform a C++ string comparison from a null-terminated buffer that is created from a named pipe connection.

Here is the relevant C++ server-side code:

```cpp
// now block for data from the pipe
wchar_t buffer[10];
DWORD numBytesRead = 0;
BOOL fSuccess = ReadFile(
    pipe,                  // handle to pipe 
    buffer,                // buffer to receive data 
    127 * sizeof(wchar_t), // size of buffer 
    &numBytesRead,         // number of bytes read 
    NULL);                 // not overlapped I/O 

// create pill logic
if (fSuccess) {
    buffer[numBytesRead / sizeof(wchar_t)] = '\0'; // null-term string
    wcout << "[*] Server recv bytes: " << numBytesRead << endl;
    printf("[*] Client sent the following message: %s \n", buffer);
    wcout << wcscmp(buffer, L"00") << endl; //attempt to compare strings
    if (buffer) {
        if (wcscmp(buffer, L"00") == 0) {
            //00 = stop - dont write / output data(pause)
            wcout << "[!] Server received stop message - now pausing" << endl;
            pill = 0;
        }
```

and the client connecting is PowerShell:

```bsh
param ($ComputerName = '.')

$npipeClient = New-Object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream($ComputerName, 'my_pipe', [System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::InOut,
                                                                [System.IO.Pipes.PipeOptions]::None, 
                                                                [System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel]::Impersonation)
$pipeReader = $pipeWriter = $null
try {
    $npipeClient.Connect()
    $pipeReader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($npipeClient)
    $pipeWriter = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($npipeClient)
    $pipeWriter.AutoFlush = $true
    # Connect Loop
    while (1) {
        write-host "[*] Server Sent: " $pipeReader.ReadLine()
        $User = Read-Host -Prompt 'Send code to server: '
        $pipeWriter.Write($User)
    }
```

Finally here is the output from the server:

```
[*] Starting pipe server!
[*] Pipe thread started!
[*] Pipe server waiting for command...
[*] Server sent bytes: 92
[*] Server recv bytes: 2
[*] Client sent the following message: 00
1
[!] Server received invalid request!
[*] Server sent bytes: 92
[*] Server recv bytes: 5
[*] Client sent the following message: 0000
1
[!] Server received invalid request!
[*] Server sent bytes: 92
[*] Server recv bytes: 1
[*] Client sent the following message:
-1
[!] Server received invalid request!
[*] Server sent bytes: 92
```

Interesting part is when I send just one character it dose not get displayed properly. I don't know if that is from how I'm printing the buffer.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @PetSerAl Currently I'm having an issue when attempting to perform a C++ string comparison: "wcout << wcscmp(buffer, L"00") << endl;" is resulting as a positive int. Rather than a zero for a exact match. where am  I going wrong here? The server output can provide you context.

Comment: In C++ code you just read bytes, but I do not see where you convert them to chars.

Comment: @PetSerAl for the Readfile win32 API it returns a pointer and size to the bytes. So in this case I need to convert them to a char array? Sorry for the dumb question, C++ is still new to me.

Comment: `StreamWriter`, by default, use UTF-8 encoding for converting chars to bytes before it write bytes into underlying `Stream`. You read bytes. Now you need decode them back to chars.